# Include path not expanding when using path variable

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I create a new c++ project. Then right click on the project -> properties -> Resources -> Linked resources, where I defined a path variable :

```
MY_PROJ_ROOT   <some_correct_path>
```

Then I went to compiler options -> Include options, where I tried to add include path combined with the path variable like this :

```
"${MY_PROJ_ROOT}/include"
```

but the include directory is not shown in the Include tab under the project menu. Instead of showing full include path (like for other includes), I get only this : `/include`.

So, am I doing something wrong when using path variable to set include? What is the correct way?

PS I checked paths, and everything I could think of, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I figured out :

Open project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Build Variables tab, and add new variables :

```
MY_PROJ_ROOT   <some_correct_path>
```

Then the variable is going to work for the includes tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try `${env_var:MY_PROJ_ROOT}`. Eclipse comes with its own schema for inserting variables. If there should be a button "Variables...", click it and you will see the various options, of which one is `env_var` that takes an environment variable name as argument. In fact, you may want to use `${project_loc}` instead of defining your own variable.

Comment: I tried with `env_var:` and it didn't work. And the "Variables" button exists for path variables, but not for include paths